# Setup CMake with SFML in VS2017

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, sfml

Just like in CLion I want to use [SFML](https://nightlybuilds.ch/project/show/1/SFML/) with Visual Studio 2017, but I'm still learning cmake and I don't know the commands or the logic of how cmake works at all. I've just seen some posts and got this litle script.

*Note: I downloaded the latest version of sfml in the link provided, I just taked the extrated directory and put alongside CMakeLists.txt in my folder*

```
#sets up the minimum version of cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

#how the project will be called
project (space_impact)

#set c++11 standard
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" -std=c++11)

#set source files
set (SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

#we add the executable of the program
add_executable (space_impact ${SOURCE_FILES})

#taked from a mac-clion tutorial, doesn't work
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SFML/cmake-modules/")
find_package (SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(space_impact ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

that thing gave me errors:

```
Error       CMake Error at SFML/cmake-modules/FindSFML.cmake:355 (message):
  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY
  SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_NETWORK_LIBRARY SFML_AUDIO_LIBRARY)        SFML/cmake-modules/FindSFML.cmake
```

I want everything to be dynamic, but I don't know how can I do that..
So my question is what should I do for **setting up correctly SFML with Cmake** in Visual Studio.
*I don't want the old-fashioned method from the official website*

**UPDATE**
Here's my location....
[image: outside]
[image: inside]

The thing is.. the `FindSFML.cmake` script it's not working...
What files should I move for make it working?

Comment: The error means that it couldn't find SFML. Do you have SFML **installed**? If yes, where is it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev as i said.. all the libraries are in the same folder SFML which is in the link i provided, outside of it... is my main.cpp

Comment: Try setting `SFML_ROOT` to `C:/Users/ramm32/Documents/SFML/` (see my answer below). This should make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is perfectly fine, except three things I'd change:

- Move the whole module detection **before** defining targets. I'm pretty sure you also have to define your include directories before.
- Your `if(SFML_FOUND)` bracket is pretty pointless right now, because you've set SFML to be required, which means it will never get past `find_package()` unless it's found.
- `-std=c++11` is a GCC only flag (MSVC will always use the latest standard, unless specified). As such you'll have to check the compiler here or use `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`.

So the "cleaned" `CMakeLists.txt` could look like this:

```
#sets up the minimum version of cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9) # personally I'd set this version as low as required; you don't have to require the cutting edge version

#how the project will be called
project (space_impact)

#set the C++ standard to be used
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

#set source files
set (SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

#look for SFML and add it
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/SFML/cmake-modules/")
find_package (SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#we add the executable of the program
add_executable (space_impact ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(space_impact ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```

Note that adding `SFML_DEPENDENCIES` to the library list is optional, unless you're using a static version of SFML.

But what about your SFML issue? Since you don't have the SFML files installed in any directory looked into by default, you'll have to tell CMake where it's found using the CMake variable `SFML_ROOT` or the environment variable of the same name.

So the first time you're invoking CMake, it could look like this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -DSFML_ROOT=path/to/sfml path/to/source
```

Comment: You can also [set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#optional-compile-features) as a portable replacement for `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Neat, is that new? Don't think I've seen it before. Updating the answer.

Comment: It has been around since CMake 3.1, but CMake features have a tendency to go largely unnoticed for a while due to well-established workarounds. Which is why I like pointing out more modern alternatives from time to time.

Comment: the `DSFML` stands for debug? and which files do I need to put there... I'll update the question

Comment: @RenatoA.No, it's short for `define` or `definition`. It sets the `SFML_ROOT` variable to the path following the `=`.

Comment: is there a way without the cli command? how to put it on the script?

Comment: @RenatoA. What do you mean?

Comment: why the command generates a bunch of vsprox files? I'm not building sfml, i have the compiled sfml already... what is happening? I setted the sfml root but now i cant execute the program

Comment: @RenatoA. That's how Cmake and other pre-build tools work. They use their own files to describe what has to be done and will then generate or update the proper files to build with your chosen toolchain. If you'd run the same command on Unix, you'd get makefiles rather than Visual Studio project files. This way you don't have to know or write all the different files, only your Cmake script.

Comment: The part of adding SFML to PATH is crucial... thanks for your time

Comment: It seems SFML moved to a new system based on imported targets, so the code above no longer works for me with SFML 2.5.1. Remove the `include_directories` call and replace the `target_link_libraries` with `target_link_libraries(space_impact PUBLIC sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-network sfml-audio)` to make it work again.

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need to compile sfml in your cmake project.

```
find_package(SFML 2.5.1 COMPONENTS system graphics audio network REQUIRED)
add_executable (AwesomeProject "AwesomeProject.cpp" "AwesomeProject.h")
target_link_libraries(AwesomeProject PRIVATE sfml-audio sfml-graphics sfml-network sfml-system)
```

Also set SFML_DIR var to your sfml folder.

Comment: thanks for an updated answer but this still lacks on info

Comment: You dont need to provide your own find_sfml.cmake the one you need is already present in sfml folder. find_package can look for that file you just need to set sfml_dir var to sfml folder so find_package could find that sfmlConfig.cmake.