# How to make CMake recognize SFML

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I am trying to write a simple chess app that I will later use for making my own chess engine. I am using C++ and SFML library (or at least I want to use it).

I am using Visual Studio Code, I have Mac OS 12.6.6 and I can't upgrade it to Mac OS 13 because my Mac is too old, therefore I cannot download the latest XCode and (from what I understand) I cannot download the version of XCode that would work on my Mac without paying for Apple developer programme, which I won't do.

I'm a complete newbie to CMake and I don't know any better alternatives (if there are), and (again, from what I understand) I have to use something like CMake to make SFML work. The problem is I have no idea how to make it work.

I've tried copying various solutions I've found in the internet, but none of them were really addressing exactly my situation and so none of them worked. Usually, I get an error:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
[cmake]   By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[cmake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but
[cmake]   CMake did not find one.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" with any of
[cmake]   the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     SFMLConfig.cmake
[cmake]     sfml-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
[cmake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[cmake]   installed.
```

Currently, my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.26.4)
project (Kenobi-bot-chess-engine
VERSION 0.1
DESCRIPTION "Chess engine in C++")

find_package(SFML REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Kenobi-bot-chess-engine ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(Kenobi-bot-chess-engine main.cpp)
```

Again, I've never used CMake before and, as for now, it is rather confusing for me, so it's quite possible that this question is silly and the problem is easy, but I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: How did you install SFML? Where did you install it? Have you added the right path to the environment variables `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` as the error message mentions?

Comment: *"I have to use something like CMake to make SFML work."* You don't need cmake at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setup CMake with SFML in VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406388/setup-cmake-with-sfml-in-vs2017)

Comment: Do exactly what the error told you to do. This error message is one of the most helpful ones you will get in programming.

Answer (score 1):

So in a nutshell the cmake, qmake, make and others are just a way to link / change ur code into an actual working thing. When it comes to the sfml, visual studio is not the only program that you can use to make sfml applications. Another good example is qt creator. I suggest you look at the official step by step guide to how to install and configure sfml on your mac machine. I'll send one link to the general installation guide and another to the xcode guide. Maybe you're trying to use a newer sfml version or such with an old xcode version. Because of your limitidness you'll have to look into what version needs what dependencies AND at what version of them you need to install.

General installation:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-vc.php

Xcode installation:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-osx.php

And if you're feeling extra spicy you can also compile it yourself:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/compile-with-cmake.php

Hope this helps and good luck!